# How would I get all links, or clips, from a specific channel on Twitch in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, twitch

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import re

req = Request("https://www.twitch.tv/directory/game/League%20of%20Legends/clips")
html_page = urlopen(req)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "html.parser")

links = []
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    links.append(link.get('href'))

print(links)
```

This is the code I have this far, I'm not too sure how I would modify it to get the clip links on Twitch.

Comment: Search on Google for “Python website scraping”, there should be more than just a few tutorials on how to start. Right now, your question is too broad, but feel free to come back if you have specific problems once you know the basics.

Comment: Just inspect the html to find which tags hold the links you want.

Answer (score 3):

The URLs are created dynamically, so just trying to load the HTML will not be enough. By looking at the request a browser makes to get the data, it is returned inside a JSON object.

You would either need to use something like `selenium` to automate a browser to get all the URLs or alternatively, requests the JSON yourself as follows:

```
import requests

url = "https://gql.twitch.tv/gql"
json_req = """[{"query":"query ClipsCards__Game($gameName: String!, $limit: Int, $cursor: Cursor, $criteria: GameClipsInput) { game(name: $gameName) { id clips(first: $limit, after: $cursor, criteria: $criteria) { pageInfo { hasNextPage __typename } edges { cursor node { id slug url embedURL title viewCount language curator { id login displayName __typename } game { id name boxArtURL(width: 52, height: 72) __typename } broadcaster { id login displayName __typename } thumbnailURL createdAt durationSeconds __typename } __typename } __typename } __typename } } ","variables":{"gameName":"League of Legends","limit":100,"criteria":{"languages":[],"filter":"LAST_DAY"},"cursor":"MjA="},"operationName":"ClipsCards__Game"}]"""
r = requests.post(url, data=json_req, headers={"client-id":"kimne78kx3ncx6brgo4mv6wki5h1ko"})
r_json = r.json()

edges = r_json[0]['data']['game']['clips']['edges']
urls = [edge['node']['url'] for edge in edges]

for url in urls:
    print url
```

This would give you the first `100` URLs starting as:

```
https://clips.twitch.tv/CourageousOnerousChoughWOOP
https://clips.twitch.tv/PhilanthropicAssiduousSwordHassaanChop
https://clips.twitch.tv/MistyThoughtfulLardPRChase
https://clips.twitch.tv/HotGoldenAmazonSSSsss
https://clips.twitch.tv/RelievedViscousPangolinOSsloth
```

Comment: Long time since I have asked this question, but just for a follow ups, how did you learn to do the JSON things?  Where can I learn that?

Comment: I picked it up by playing with the developer features of Firefox (similar in other browser). In your case, the javascript in the HTML was making a request to get the info which I could see in the network tools. I then copied the request made.